# NASM: why is cmp byte[rdi], byte[rsi] not compiling?

Tags: compilation, nasm

Why this following nasm code does not compile :

```
cmp byte [rdi], byte [rsi]
```

whereas this code compiles:

```
mov al, byte [rsi]
cmp byte [rdi], al
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two indirect arguments are not supported. And why not use cmpsb, which compares these two bytes directly?

Comment: I'm just curious and beginner ^^